# AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate and HLS does not work?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, avasset, avurlasset

For me it's not working with "m3u8" url both on Simulator and real device (iPhone 5S).
In the same time, Apple demo working good, but I don't see any difference.
And with other url extensions it's ok (e.g., "m3u9" on the end of the url)

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // if I change m3u8 to different file extension, it's working good
        let url = NSURL(string: "cplp://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8") 

        let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url!, options: nil)
        asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_queue_create("AVARLDelegateDemo loader", nil))

        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        player.play()
    }

    func resourceLoader(resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {

        NSLog("This method is never called in case of m3u8 url")

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found how to fix it, but still don't understand why it's happening only for "m3u8" links.

Need to save strong `player` or, at least, `item` reference.
Thanks, Apple, for the docs. :sarcasm:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {
    var player: AVPlayer! // <-- the fix

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // if I change m3u8 to different file extension, it's working good
        let url = NSURL(string: "cplp://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8") 

        let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url!, options: nil)
        asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_queue_create("AVARLDelegateDemo loader", nil))

        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item) // <-- the fix
        player.play()
    }

    func resourceLoader(resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {

        NSLog("This method is never called in case of m3u8 url")

        return true
    }
}
```